# GRPC C++ TLS Client grpc::SslCredentials() method not returning

Tags: c++, grpc

What version of gRPC and what language are you using?
1.29

What operating system (Linux, Windows,...) and version?
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)

What runtime / compiler are you using (e.g. python version or version of gcc)
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

What did you do?
Creating client SslCredentialsOptions
If i use the same code in simple application it's working perfectly.
When integrated in shared library and used that lib in multithread application. The channel not created.
When did debugging i found that grpc::SslCredentials() method not returning.

What did you expect to see?
channel created and connection establihed.
Enabled logs
export GRPC_TRACE=all
export GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
no logs generated in console.

What did you see instead?
grpc::SslCredentials() method not returning and channel not created.
I tried with both shared libs and static libs.

Answer (score 0):

```
Used the following code


grpc::SslCredentialsOptions sslops;
{
    std::string client    =   "";
    std::string key     =   "";
    std::string root    =   "";
    std::string clientcert    =   "/cert/client.crt";
    std::string keycert    =   "/cert/client.key";
    std::string rootcert    =   "/cert/ca.crt";
    SCMSSLCPPContext::read( clientcert, client);
    SCMSSLCPPContext::read( keycert, key);
    SCMSSLCPPContext::read( rootcert, root);
    sslops = { root, key, cert };
    //std::shared_ptr<grpc::ChannelCredentials> creds = grpc::SslCredentials(sslops);
    auto channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(sslops);
    auto channel = grpc::CreateChannel("localhost:14021", channel_creds );
}
```

Comment: grpc::SslCredentials() method not returning